# How to calculate the sum of individual elements from two 2D arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to write a function `addArrays` which will, as parameters, take two 2D arrays of type `int` and of dimensions 3x4, and it's job is to add individual elements of each index from the given arrays and display it in the console.

In `main()`, I created two 2D arrays `arrA` and `arrB` of appropriate sizes with intitialized members and check the functionality of the created function.

My code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void addArrays(int x[3][4], int y[3][4]);

int main()
{
    int arrA[3][4] = { {7, 8, 13, 22}, {56, 4, 78, 3}, {22, 13, 46, 5} };
    int arrB[3][4] = { {32, 47, 56, 14}, {33, 100, 19, 64}, {4, 18, 157, 84} };
}

void addArrays(int x[3][4], int y[3][4])
{
}
```

Honestly, I know how to work with 1D arrays, but not displaying the sum of all individual elements. I know I have to use a for loop, but again, I'm confused as to how to pass in a 2D array and use it.

Comment: You should use loops. Do you know how to print elements of one 3x4 array?

Comment: Honestly, I don't. I know how to work with 1D arrays, but not displaying the sum of all individual elements. I know I have to use a for loop, but again, I'm confused as to how to pass in a 2D array into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention you know how to work with 1D arrays, it's the same for 2D arrays, only with one more dimension.

In a 1D array you use `arrA[0]` to access the first element of the array, in a 2D array you use `arrA[0][0]` to access the first element in the first line of the array, `arrA[0][1]` to access the second element in the first line of the array. To access the first element in the second line you would use `arrA[1][0]` and so on, you get the idea.

So to loop through all the elements in the array you can use nested loops like so:

```
void addArrays(int x[3][4], int y[3][4])                                        
{
    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++){    // make sure to use the correct dimensions
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){ // 3 lines and 4 columns
           // x[i][j] accesses elements in array x
           // y[i][j] accesses elements in array y
        }
    }
}
```

I think you'll manage to do the math yourself. After that you just need to send data to the standard output, ***i.e.*** to print data in the console. For that, as you may know, you use [`std::cout`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout).

**Side notes:**

- In the function `void addArrays(int x[3][4], int y[3][4]){...}` you may omit the first dimension of the array ***i.e.*** `int x[][4]` or `int (*x)[4]` instead of `int x[3][4]`, since the argument will decay to a pointer to array.
- Since it seems that you are not to change the values of the passed arrays, using `const` is recommend. You would have `void addArrays(const int (*x)[4], const int (*y)[4]);`
- As you are using C++, you can take advantage of the possibility of using references, something like `void addArrays(const int (&x)[3][4], const int (&y)[3][4]){/*same code*/}`, the benefit being you must pass a correct object to the function otherwise the program will fail to compile whereas in the previous versions if you pass, for example, `NULL`, ***i.e.*** `addArrays(arrA, NULL);` the program will compile fine but will result in undefined behavior when you run it. References are safer and you should use them when possible.
- It's more or less consensual among more experienced C++ programmers that the usage of [`using namespace std;` is not a good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/6865932), you can read more about it, and find alternatives following the link.

Answer (score 0):

I will start this for you and try to give you an idea of the general structure, but since you have not shown your attempt at the problem I won't fill things in for you.

The basic idea here when looping through 2D arrays (of size `M`x`N`) is that you can really just think about it in terms of looping through `M` arrays of length `N`.

```
void loopThroughArray(int arr[M][N])
{
  // Loop over M arrays
  for (int m = 0; m < M; ++m) {
    // For each m'th array, loop over its N contents
    for (int n = 0; n < N; ++n) {
      // Doing work
      arr[m][n] = 1234;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If I understood correctly however, there have to be 2 parameters in one function. Like `(int x[3][4], int y[3][4])`

Comment: How would I loop through already set rows and columns?

Comment: Right, I am not giving you the code to solve your exact problem here. I am giving you a code snippet to help you understand how to go about solving your problem. Please read [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) about asking homework problems.

Comment: That's okay. Thank you.

Comment: In your case since you know your arrays are both 3x4, you can hard-code `M` and `N` as 3 and 4 respectively in the loops. Otherwise you would have to either pass the array sizes in as additional parameters to the function (i.e. `void addArrays(int arr1[][], int arr2[][], int M, int N)` or as template parameters.

Comment: @JacobFaib no, you must specify all but the first dimension. This can work: `void addArrays(int arr1[][N], int arr2[][N],int M)`